# Can you read pragma statements on command line startup in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I use the command line sqlite3 executable to check queries I make from my code.

Is there a way to read in pragma statements or other session setup (".mode csv" for example) when the executable starts up?

I know I can do a ".read " once I'm in, but that's tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a `.sqliterc`  file in your home directory with
the commands you want executed each time you start
the sqlite3 command line tool.

Unix and Linux use `~/.sqliterc`; Windows tries to find the
location of .sqliterc using the environment variables
`USERPROFILE` `HOME` `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`.

Comment: That easy, huh?  How come that is not documented anywhere?  Or at least not that I could find on the homepage.  Thanks.